# free space in the design editor but not on the device?

Tags: android

I'm designing a UI using android studio and my problem is that I see a free space on the design editor and the emulator but not on the device .

here is how it looks on the design editor and the emulator
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NTjI.png)

and here is how it looks on the device
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7xUU.png)

and here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MyPfe.ClientInterface">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/global_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/Butt_layout"
        android:weightSum="2"


        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_car" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Document à transmettre"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/backgroundcolor"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/sogreen"/>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                    android:text="CONTRAT AUTO N°"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="nome et prenom"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>



              </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                        android:text="Début du contrat le"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="Échéance le"
                        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>



                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>





        </LinearLayout>












        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2"

            >

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cons_cont_lin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Consulter mon                    contrat"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Modifier mon                      contrat"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Suivre un                             sinistre"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_consulter_contrat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Déclarer un                       sininstre"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Butt_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_depannage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/sogreen"
            android:text="URGENCE ET DÉPANNAGE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/backgroundcolor"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use different device in `preview`. Probably your emulator has different size than in preview (I see `Pixel` with `API 28`)

Comment: I tried it's the same ... the preview didn't change .

Comment: Main question - do you need this space **ON DEVICE** or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with your rendering. The device resolution in the emulator and designer view is higher than your real device. Try setting the designer or your emulator to the same width and height as your device and you will see its all the same.

From what I see, the lower part containing the icons is aligned to the baseline/bottom etc. of the parent container or something like that. I think your device is 4.5" or 5" screen while your designer and your emulator is a 6" screen.